# How to get daily ranking of iOS and Android app store ranking?

Tags: app-store, android-market-filtering

I wonder how we can subscribe iOS and/or Android hourly/daily app ranking from the server programmatically.

I hope there is a way to get it by using their REST API.

Comment: No idea what you want to do. In an app? What language / platform? What do you mean with subscribing? You have to clarify your question.

Comment: I guess it would be a REST API. The subscribing means to connect to their server to get ranking data, e.g. current ranking of Utility category in France market of iOS app store, by using their web API. However it is just my guess. I am open to any method, any OS, and any languages to do this.